# Laravel 5.0 Eloquent 3rd level relationships

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

i have three tables

**Property:**

1. property_id
2. title

**Property Prices:**

1. property_price_id
2. currency_id
3. price

**currencies**

1. currency_id
2. title

**Property Model:**

```
public function PropertyPrice(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\PropertyPrice','property_id');
}
```

**property Price Model:**

```
 public function Currency(){

         return $this->belongsTo('App\Currency','currency_id');  
}

 public function Property(){

       return $this->belongsTo('App\Property','property_id');
}
```

**Currency Model**

```
public function PropertyPrice(){

  return $this->hasMany('App\PropertyPrice','currency_id');
}
```

Now i am running this Eloquent command for getting properties with prices,

```
Property::with('PropertyPrice')->orderBy('ordering','desc')->paginate(10);
```

but i am confused how to get the currency title? please note i have seen the example provided on official documentation under "Has Many Through" but its a different example , i am unable to relate to it.

please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was doing some experiments and found out the answer,

```
Property::with(['PropertyPrice' => function($query){
                                      $query->with('Currency');
                                   }
               ])->orderBy('ordering','desc')->paginate($per_page);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$properties = Property::with('PropertyPrice')->orderBy('ordering','desc')->paginate(10);
```

then

```
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $currency_title = $property->PropertyPrice->Currency->title;
}
```

using the same logic, you could do that in your view as well

Comment: Thanks bro, i got my answer by experiments but your tip is also very beneficial , thanks for your time